# How to convert HTML FORM to simple html code in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need to convert this HTML FORM

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['news.destroy', $news->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
 <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
{!! Form::close() !!}
<div class="pull-right"><em>{{'Author - ' . $news->author }}</em></div>
```

To a simple HTML form

I have tried this, but it didn't work

```
<form action="{{ route('news.destroy', $news->id, ['method' => 'delete']) }}">
 <input type="submit" value="delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: action should be `{{ route('news.destroy', $news->id) }}` and for method add a hidden input `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">`

Comment: I need to button it removes items. 
The fact that you gave me , it is not correct , the button " Delete " all gone

Comment: When I click to button I jump this link http://localhost:8000/news/1?

Comment: Check the redirection after in destroy() method. 
Also you probably will have to include the csrf token. https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('news.destroy', $news->id)}}" accept-     charset="UTF-8">
     <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Please add more details or an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Basically you missed the method="post" some time method="delete" not work in some browser so we use post method for delete  like you are deleting news in this scenario.